# An error in application of Runge's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation

I have read the following theorem in Complex Analysis by Cufi and Bruna on Page 420:

> Runge's theorem for open sets: An open set $U$ has the property that every holomorphic function on $U$ is the uniform limit on compact sets of $U$ of a sequence of polynomials, if and only if $\mathbb C \setminus U$ has **no** bounded connected component.

Now I came across the following question:

> For which among the following functions $f(z)$ defined on $G=\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, is there no sequence of polynomials approximating $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subsets of $G$?
>
> $(a)\ e^z \\(b)\ \frac1z\\(c)\ z^2\\(d)\ \frac1{z^2}$

The answer according to me should be $(b)$ and $(d)$.

But if I try to apply the above theorem, I see that all the functions are holomorphic on $G$(open) and $\mathbb C \setminus G=\{0\}$ which has a bounded connected component, namely $\{0\}$. So according to the theorem, the correct answer should be $(a),(b),(c)$ and $(d)$.

> Where am I going wrong in applying the theorem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why should (a), say, be the correct answer? We are working here with $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, indeed, but what you can deduce from Runge's theorem is that there is *some* holomorphic function $f$ defined on that set for which there is no sequence of polynomials approximating $f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, not that that's true for *all* holomorphic functions defined there.

Comment: Oh that was really silly of me.

Comment: @SahibaArora Would you please mark my answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes I'm just waiting for the required time after which the system allows me to do that.

Comment: Any idea about why someone downvoted my answer? This question is for all, not just for Sahiba Arora.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the answer to be downvoted.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir, May I know how do you write like this . 'can deduce from Runge's theorem is that there is *some* holomorphic function $f$ defined on that set for which there is no sequence of polynomials approximating $f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, not that that's true for *all* holomorphic functions defined there.' Can you explain?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I did not express my self correctly. What I meant was that, since the hypothesis of Runge's theorem don't hold, you cannot assert that it's conclusion is true, but all that this means is that there *may* be some sequence of polynomial functions approximating $f$ on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos all that this means is that there may be some sequence of polynomial functions approximating $f$ on compact subsets of C∖{0}. May I know, How it is coming?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I am sorry, but I don't know how to explain that something *may* happen. It's too basic.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I will try my level best to find the answer. May I ask the question related to this here?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Of course you can.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $f$  is analytic in some compact set. $f$ is continuous there. We know the set of polynomial functions in a compact set is dense in the set of continuous function in that compact set. sir, Am I correct?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Yes, you are.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you sir.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. According to this None is right. Every function given in the option has an only analytic part in the Laurent series expansion with respect to the points from $\mathbb C-\{0\}$. Sir, am I correct?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Options (b) and (d) are right; the others are wrong.

Comment: sir, I understood my mistake. Thank you very much sir @JoséCarlosSantos.